# Cargar dinámicamente css en angular

Tags: angular

Estoy haciendo un `SPA` con soporte para `dark-mode` pero me carga el nombre de la variable y no el valor

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'App-title';

  ngOnInit(){
    var local = localStorage.getItem("theme") || "light-theme";
    this.loadStyle(local == "light-theme" ? "light-theme":"dark-theme");
  }

  constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document) {}

  loadStyle(styleName: string) {
    const head = this.document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];

    let themeLink = this.document.getElementById(
      'client-theme'
    ) as HTMLLinkElement;
    if (themeLink) {
      themeLink.href = styleName;
    } else {
      const style = this.document.createElement('link');
      style.id = 'client-theme';
      style.rel = 'stylesheet';
      style.href = `${styleName}`;

      head.appendChild(style);
    }
  }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Esto es por que te falta concatenar la extensión del archivo en este caso *light-theme.css* o *dark-theme.css*. Yo te recomendaría que mejor usaras un solo archivo y hagas la diferencia del "theme" con una clase ***.dark-theme , .light-theme***, de esta manera solo tendrías que cambiar el nombre de la clase en tu html. Te dejo una pagina de referencia que lo explica muy bien: [Dark Theme for your Angular app](https://dev.to/adrianbudzynski/dark-theme-for-your-angular-app-1664)